# Java File not being printed into ArrayList with Scanner

Tags: java

I am coding software to automatically schedule employees (meant to be used for restaurants/retail businesses).

I am having trouble using a Scanner to break my file up into an ArrayList of Strings. Please help.

```
 private static void generateStoreData() {
        
        File storeData = null;
        //creation of storeData file
        try {
            storeData = new File("storeData.txt");
            if (!(storeData.exists()))
                storeData.createNewFile();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            clearScreen();
            System.out.print("There was an error locating your file. Exiting program.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //putting data into List of Strings
        ArrayList<String> storeDataLines = readFileData(storeData);

        System.out.print(storeDataLines);
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> readFileData(File fileName) {

        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileName);
            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                lines.add(line);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            clearScreen();
            System.out.print("There was an error reading from this file.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

I have attached the two methods dealing with the files for reference.

This is the text file I am working with for testing.

```
STORE HOURS:

Sunday: CLOSED
Monday: 5:00-21:00
Tuesday: 5:00-21:00
Wednesday: 5:00-21:00
Thursday: 5:00-21:00
Friday: 5:00-21:00
Saturday: 5:00-21:00
```

Comment: Let me guess: you get "There was an error reading from this file." but don't know what went wrong? (Hint: don't swallow exceptions but log them - otherwise you'll never know the cause for the exception)

Comment: @Shane Frantz You need to be more specific to what your problem is. It could be a lot of things, so please specify exactly what occurs. I can make a guess and say that your file path might not be correct when initializing your storeData variable.

Comment: @Thomas The output of the program is a blank ArrayList.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Try to post a [mcve].

Comment: @ShaneFrantz because you're not reading the file you intended to and instead creating a blank file after `!(storeData.exists())`. Put a breakpoint there and see if you're hitting `storeData.createNewFile();`

Comment: Probably file path is incorrect.

Comment: @Shane Frantz Most likely your file path is wrong and it’s creating a new blank txt file. Your if file does not exist statement does this. Try deleting that if statement to verify that the file path is incorrect.